# Why do mobs spawn in my house?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

It's a fairly big home, and I used up a lot of glow stone and torches to light it up, would it still not be enough?

Comment: "A lot" isn't quite specific...

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me normally its because somewhere in your house is still dark or the lights quite dim in your house

Comment: @A.Chestnut not a problem